# Nice integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\log(x)}{e^{x^2}+1}dx=?$

Tags: logarithms, power-series, exponential-function, improper-integrals

Prove that :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\log(x)}{e^{x^2}+1}dx=\frac{-1}{8}\log^2(2)$$

This result is surprisingly elegant and sober .

I have tried integration by part but I don't see a good way .

I have tried power series with :

$$ \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{x^2}+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\mathrm{e}^{-nx^2}} $$

And get a infinite sum instead of an integral but I become quickly stuck .

furthermore I don't see an obvious substitution to this integral .

Finally we have:
$$\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{\log x}{e^x+1}\,dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x\log x}{e^{x^2}+1}\,dx$$
I prefer hints but a detailed answer is also good .

Any helps is greatly appreciated

Thanks a lot .

Comment: From $\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t+1}dt=\Gamma(s)\eta(s)$, we see that \begin{align}f(s)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^s}{e^{x^2}+1}dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{\frac{s+1}{2}-1}}{e^t+1}dt\\&=\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)\eta\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right).\end{align}Hence, \begin{align}f'(s)&=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^s\ln x}{e^{x^2}+1}dx\\&=\frac14\Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)\eta'\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)+\frac14\Gamma'\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)\eta\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right).\end{align}Since $f'(1)$ is the required value, we need to show $$\eta'(1)+\Gamma'(1)\ln 2=-\frac{1}{2}\ln^22.$$

Comment: Apparently $\Gamma'(1)=-\gamma$ and $\eta'(1)=-\frac12\ln^22+\gamma\ln 2$ from [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%27%5B1%5D) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Derivatives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of a series expansion $$\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{x^2}+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\mathrm{e}^{-nx^2}}$$ is very good since
$$\int x \log (x)\,e^{-n x^2} \,dx=\frac{\text{Ei}\left(-n x^2\right)-2 e^{-n x^2} \log (x)}{4 n}$$
$$\int_0^\infty x \log (x)\,e^{-n x^2} \,dx=-\frac{\log (n)+\gamma }{4 n}$$ and performing the summation
$$-\frac{1}{8} \log (2) (\log (2)-2 \gamma )-\frac{1}{4} \gamma  \log (2)=-\frac{1}{8} \log ^2(2)$$

Answer (score 5):

The last relation given in the question *is* a substitution $u=x^2$. Then any of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585960) show that $\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{e^x+1}=-\frac12\log^22$, and the original integral follows.